# JPG-image becomes corrupted or damaged when sent over socket in java

Tags: java, sockets, io, javax.imageio

I'm attempting to send a JPEG-image over a socket from a client to server in java. I write the image into a File-object and then using FileInputStream I read it into a Byte[] array before sending the array over the socket. Below is code for client.

```
class TestingClient {
    Socket s;
    public TestingClient () {
        try {
            s = new Socket("localhost", 666);
        }catch (UnknownHostException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String imgPath = "C:/Users/huehuehue/Documents/Uni/D0036D/prick1.JPG";
        File file = new File(imgPath);
        byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        try {
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
            fin.read(bFile);
            fin.close();
            OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
            os.write(bFile, 0, bFile.length);
            os.close();
            System.out.println();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The server writes out the recieved bytes into two separate ".JPG"-files and then reads the recieved bytes into a buffered image, which is called upon when instantiating a JLabel when adding it to a simple JFrame. The files themselves are non-viewable through windows photo viewer which states for both of them "can't open this picture because the file appears to be damaged, corrupted, or is too large". An unhandled exception "java.lang.NullPointerException" is thrown when the program tries to instantiate the JLabel with the buffered image. All the console messages in code print out as they should though. Below is code for server.

```
public class TestingServer {

    InetAddress serverAddr;
    BufferedImage img;

    private class frame extends JFrame {

        JLabel test;

        private class aspectRatio {
            int w = 16, h = 9;
        }

        public frame (BufferedImage y) {
            aspectRatio aR = new aspectRatio ();
            this.setVisible(true);
            this.setSize(50*aR.w, 50*aR.h);
            this.setTitle("TESTING");
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            this.setLayout(null);
            this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

            this.add(test = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(y)));
            test.setBounds(25*aR.w, 13*aR.h, 15*aR.w, 10*aR.h);
        }

    }

    public TestingServer () {
        ServerSocket serverSocket;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(666);
            Socket connect = serverSocket.accept();

        System.out.println("So we read");
        InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream());
        FileOutputStream fos1 = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/Users/huehuehue/Documents/Uni/D0036D/test1.JPG"));
        int c=0;
        while ((c = ir.read()) != -1) {
            fos1.write(ir.read());
        }
        fos1.close();
        System.out.println("finito1");

        FileOutputStream fos2 = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/Users/huehuehue/Documents/Uni/D0036D/test2.JPG"));
        byte[] barr = new byte[34534];
        int i = 0;
        c = 0;
        while ((c = ir.read()) != -1) {
             barr[i] = (byte) c;
             i++;
        }
        fos2.write(barr,0,i+1);
        fos2.close();
        System.out.println("finito2");

        img = ImageIO.read(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(barr, 0, i)));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("image buffered");

        frame f = new frame(img);

    }

}
```

I am sort of stuck and any help or guidance is appreciated :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using an InputStreamReader, which tries to convert the bytes of the image into characters. You should use the InputStream directly, without a Reader. Or preferably use a `BufferedInputStream`

Also, in filling the second file, you continue to read from the input stream, although it has already given you -1 indicating the end of stream. You should, instead, open both files before the loop, and write the byte you read from the input stream twice - once into the first file and once into the second file.

Another problem is that you call `ir.read()` again inside the loop (filling the first file). This discards the byte you have already read, and reads the next one. So in essence you are reading every second byte.

So you need to do something along the lines of:

```
iStream = new BufferedInputStream(connect.getInputStream());

FileOutputStream fos1 = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/Users/huehuehue/Documents/Uni/D0036D/test1.JPG"));
FileOutputStream fos2 = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/Users/huehuehue/Documents/Uni/D0036D/test2.JPG"));
int c=0;
while ((c = iStream.read()) != -1) {
    fos1.write(c);
    fos2.write(c);
}
fos1.close();
fos2.close();
iStream.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for response cleared up a lot, particularly why the 2nd file turned out empty when I tried writing them to .txt file instead. I think I can see why a BufferedInputStream would be better as the data is not immediately lost upon reading it (right?), but is it needed here?

Comment: No, actually, the reason is that reading one byte at a time accrues a lot of overhead on system calls. A BufferedInputStream reads several bytes together, only making a single system call for all of them together, and keeps them around in a buffer. When you ask it for the next byte, it simply fetches it from the buffer and saves a lot of system resources.